# I cannot charge my tablet

Tags: usb, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab

I only have a USB cable to charge my tablet and I plugged it into my laptop to charge and a little red X shows up on the battery thing. How can I charge my tablet?

Comment: Have you tried swapping another cable? Does the battery icon change when tablet is plugged in?

Answer (score 2):

A computer's usb port does not supply enough current to charge your tablet. The tablet takes roughly 1A or 1,000mA to charge, a desktop's usb port only puts out about 500mA. Some laptops just can't provide the specified 500mA and will not charge it at all. YMMV

You can charge it though, only very slowly, AND the tablet has to be completely turned off.

Comment: It is only going to take more time to charge when charging current is low (i.e. limited to 500mA as said) and not totally stop charging. Hence the moment there is a current flow towards the battery the battery icon (if shown) will indicate it - no matter how low the battery is.